# How to keep track of all images on a device in a react native app?

Tags: react-native

I want to keep track of all images on a device for a gallery app. I can fetch all images on device on load but don't want to do it repeatedly. What is a better way to do it?

If I only fetch new images on subsequent fetch, how do I know if an image from previous fetch has been deleted? Also is there way to know if a new image has been added to device?

Answer (score 0):

You can sync gallery and store that data into your DB. Along with Data try to store last sync date and time. So next time when you sync you just have to fetch those images whose modification date is later than sync date and time.